# YSLSearchViewController not working on iOS 9 because of SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift

After being not able to install the [Yahoo Search SDK](https://developer.yahoo.com/search-sdk/) via CocoaPods on iOS 9, I managed to install it manually.

But now I want to use the delegate method “didSearchToLink” of YSLSearchViewController, but it won’t get called. Instead it opens the selected link in a SFSafariViewController.
This is how i set it up:

```
let settings:YSLSearchViewControllerSettings = YSLSearchViewControllerSettings()
settings.enableSearchToLink = true
let searchViewController = YSLSearchViewController(settings: settings)
searchViewController.setSearchResultTypes([YSLSearchResultTypeImage])
self.presentViewController(searchViewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Unfortunately the YSLSearchViewController isn't very well documented at all and I'm somehow not able to see the source code of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which wasn't documented at all.
After implementing the following function, it works perfectly now:

```
func shouldSearchViewController(searchViewController: YSLSearchViewController!, previewSearchToLinkForSearchResultType searchResultType: String!) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```